# CSS Transition not working in Firebug

Tags: html, css

I was updating my online showcase today and all of the sudden I noticed that my link transition stopped working.

My website is: https://michielelshout.nl/

As you can see in the *default.css* on line 3, there's the code for the transition. When I check my file in Firebug, the transition isn't there. Even when I force it with *!important*.

In my admin it works fine. I've been scratching my head on it for a whole day now. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Edit* The CSS Code:

```
a {color:#FFC107;text-decoration:none;-moz-transition:all .3s ease 0;-ms-    transition:all .3s ease 0;-o-transition:all .3s ease 0;-webkit-transition:all .3s ease 0;transition:all .3s ease 0}
```

Comment: Please add the relevant code to the question, because once you fix it, nobody will be able to understand your problem anymore.

Comment: Vendor prefixes are not needed for transition.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the effect by removing the last zero after "ease" from the CSS. Your current shorthand is not valid.

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/transition

Comment: Very strange. It always worked, even with the 0 at the end. But still, thank you very much.